# How can I put giant writing in Python?

Tags: python, python-idle

How could I make a word in giant text (for example “welcome” but giant)? I know that it's possible to change the console to make the font larger but I need it for just the word.

Comment: Hello when you say giant, do you mean text size or to upper case?

Comment: On what sort of display surface? A web browser? Tkinter window? Console? You could potentially write a multiline ascii art of the word in the console. Or perhaps the console supports formatting controls.

Comment: text size and its on python idle

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve this problem

1 - Change the font in the python shell. Go to configure IDLE , go to the fonts tab and change the size value. Then apply the changes

2 - Using ASCII art. You can use ASCII art generators or use the python package pyfiglet(python version of figlet).

Example with pyfiglet

```
import pyfiglet
  
result = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Hello World")
print(result)
```

Pyfiglet also allows you to use many fonts , you can read their documentation for the everything else.

Hope this helps :)